# Remove pager from frontpage

Tags: 7, paging, nodes

On the frontpage of my drupal site I have set up multiple blocks that display content from different views however, in the Content block region my news block is showing a pager that I am unable to remove.

In the news block I have configured the Pager settings to display a specified number of items
and to use a more link that says view all. But the settings will not work in the content block region.

I have also tried to configure the frontpage with similar Pager settings and still no luck.

**System Information:**

- Theme: Bartik 7.12

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct display ? Views UI can be misleading at times, especially if you use views with several displays.

Comment: The view I was using is for the index page so I am sure i'm working with the correct view. When i'm in path            **Home » Administration » Structure » Views** I am able to see the changes I have made below the auto preview but the index page itself doesn't display the changes.

Comment: It doesn't prove you're modifying the correct display. Does your view has only one display ? It can be something else, such as a cache issue. Did you try to clear it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. It had to do with the defaults of the page view path.

In the Front Page View I changed the page settings path to /home and went into 
**Configuration >> Site information** and scrolled down to the Front Page settings.

I set the default front page url to home and the pager was removed as per my configuration of the frontpage Page pager settings.